# Iterate through Object keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, simplecart

Having an object like this:

```
req.body = {
    currency : "USD",
    item_name_1: "something",
    item_price_1: "something else",
    item_name_2: "something",
    item_price_2: "something else",
    item_name_3: "something",
    item_price_3: "something else",
    address: "some address"   
    itemCount: 3     
}
```

What is the best way to only get the key/value pairs of only item names??, I would try something like this but of course it doesn't work:

```
var cart= "";
for (var i=1; i<= req.body.itemCount;i++){
    cart += req.body.item_name_+i+
        " "+req.body.item_price_+i;       
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to grab a value from an Object based on a string literal, or a String, you'll need to use `[]` notation where the value between the `[]` is a string. You can build a string from string literals and variables via the `+` operator. Change your string concatenation to this:

```
cart += req.body["item_name_" + i] 
        + " " 
        + req.body["item_price_" + i];
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
req.body.item_name_+i
```

This will work:

```
req.body["item_name_" + i]
```

However, I strongly advise you to rethink your approach if you can, and refactor your data into this:

```
req.body = {
    currency : "USD",
    items: [
        { name: "something", price: "something else" },
        { name: "something", price: "something else" },
        { name: "something", price: "something else" }
    ],
    address: "some address"   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check this so might need to mess around with it but I believe it'll be this:

```
req.body["item_name_" + i]
```

and

```
req.body["item_price_" + i]
```